# SQL string or Normal string

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I tried looking for an answer but didn't find anything useful. Is there any difference functionality-wise between SQL String and String? If not then what could be the purpose of the below code:

```
public static String FormatSQL (string value) {
  if (value.Length == 0) || (value == null) {
    return "NULL"
  }
  else {
    return "'" + value.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))` instead of `if (value.length == 0) || (value == null)`

Comment: There's no `SQL string or Normal string`. There are just strings. And returning a string containing `NULL` instead of an actual null isn't just evil, it's actually part of one of the funniest real-life gaffes in IT. There actually is a guy named Null

Comment: What is this code trying to do? Are you trying to sanitize input so you can generate dynamic SQL? This will never work, in any language, any database. This leaves you wide open to SQL injection and conversion errors. Imagine if someone typed `'; drop table users;--`. Use parameterized queries instead. It's actually a *lot* easier than concatenating strings

Comment: The only purpose this could be used for would be to dynamically contatenate values into a SQL string - never a good idea, sql queries should always be parameterised.

Comment: The code suggest it's used as a helper to inject values into SQL statements. This is a very bad practice. It would be much better to use a parameterized (prepared) query.

Comment: Yes, I am using the parametrized query and the parameter value is is being processed through this conversion function.So, is it necessary to use this function before paramets query or i can directly pass the string value in sql parameter query

Comment: The purpose is mainly to escape the single quote character. By the way, that code will throw an error when value is null (value.lenght is evaluated before value == null).

Comment: @Carlos why would they want to escape single character?

Comment: Ask the person that wrote it or ask someone at your giant, multi-national outsourcing. firm. Without seeing how that function is used, strangers can only guess. And as the guesses imply, it is used to inject strings into a query which contradicts your statement about parameterization. You need to examine the code using this function (and post it if you want a definitive answer).

Comment: @RAHULRAWAT, values in parameterized queries [do not need to be escaped](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/) and do not have string values of `NULL`. So what the code does is not necessary and will add add quotes not present in the original value and persist strings with value "NULL."

Comment: @RAHULRAWAT There are many possible reasons, specially to avoid runtime exceptions when using the string that contains a single quota. But be careful with SQL injection when doing such things.

Answer (score 0):

its just return `PARAMET'ER`  to  `'PARAMET''ER'`  . Most Probably in the code, its used to add some filter on current SQL statements (bad idea: sql injection problems ....).